# Error if file already doesn't exist fso.OpenTextFile method

Tags: vbscript

I'm using the `OpenTextFile` method for appending some text to a log file.

```
Sub saveStringToFile(filename, text)
    Dim fso, f
    Set f = fileSysObject.OpenTextFile(filename, 8)
    f.Write text
    f.Close
End Sub
```

It works fine if the file exists already, but generates a runtime error if the target file is not found.

Is there any flag for `OpenTextFile` or an alternate method to create a new file & append if file doesn't exist already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

> ```
> object.OpenTextFile(filename[, iomode[, create[, format]]])
> ```
>
> **Arguments**
>   [...]
>   *create*
>       Optional. Boolean value that indicates whether a new file can be created if the specified *filename* doesn't exist. The value is **True** if a new file is created, **False** if it isn't created. If omitted, a new file isn't created.

Call `OpenTextFile` with the 3<sup>rd</sup> parameter set to `True` in order to create the file if it doesn't exist:

```
Set f = fileSysObject.OpenTextFile(filename, 8, True)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer. I've WSH 5.6 offline documentation. Couldn't locate given information.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably not a great solution, though it does it and I'm going with it, JUST FOR NOW =)

```
Sub saveStringToFile(filename, text)
    If fileSysObject.FileExists(filename) Then
        Dim f
        Set f = fileSysObject.OpenTextFile(filename, 8)
        f.Write text
        f.Close
    Else
        Set f1 = fileSysObject.CreateTextFile(filename, True)
        f1.Write text
        f1.Close
    End If

End Sub
```

Will appreciate a better solution, if any.